# What do you choose when leveling up?

Tags: diablo-iii

I leveled up a few times as the Wizard, and I don't understand my choices when I level up. There is always a "suggested" skill or rune, and I click Accept.

What can I do besides accepting? How do I customize a particular build? Can ignore certain skills and buff others?

Comment: Only runes/skills that are new for this level are highlighted. I am not aware that the game makes suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no choices when you level up.

You unlock new skills/passives/runes, but they're always unlocked at certain levels, you never have to choose.

Your only choices in this game are what gear you want to wear, and what skills/passives/runes you want to use *right at this very moment*, since you can change any of those things at a moments notice.

You don't pick which skills to unlock, and you don't pick where to allocate your stats.

When you level up, just check what new thing you've unlocked and decide whether you like it better or worse than what you're currently using.

Comment: I have no idea what Blizzard were thinking when they removed these aspects from the game.

Comment: They were probably thinking that the old skill system was horribly unintuitive for new players and not a lot of fun when you realized your build was completely ass backwards and had no real way to change it or fix it save to start over.

Comment: I love the new system, imo it is really great, don't have to level a new char to try a new spec or find out I got 2 points to much in str that could have gone in to vit when I get new items.